# Swift 3 Dismissing all view controllers beside current one

Tags: swift, segue, dismissviewcontroller

I have seen lots of answers on how to go to the root view controller, but I want to keep open the view controller that is currently being shown but then dismiss all view controllers that came prior to this current view controller.

EDIT: This is while NOT using a navigation controller.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you're not using a navigation controller, what **are** you doing to show different view controllers?

Comment: Segues, self.performSegue(segueName)

Comment: This seems odd.  Why do you want to do this? What are you trying to accomplish?